# How do I change datatype to object and open as it saved?

Tags: python, types

```
df[col] = df[col].astype('object')
df.to_csv('dataset.csv', index = False)
```

My Problem Is when I save like this and open the saved dataset. The column with changed type is back to int.

```
saved_df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
saved_df[col].info()
```

Column | Dtype

col | int64

Comment: The CSV format does not store any information about data type, so you need to tell Pandas about the data type when you read the data back.

Comment: `csv` is an untyped format. It especially doesn't know about numpy's object type.

Answer (score 0):

When [reading a csv file with Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can specify the dtype with the dtype argument.

In your case, that would be:

```
saved_df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', dtype={col: object})
```